# GPT-2: How do I speed up/optimize token text generation?

Tags: openai-api, gpt-2

I am trying to generate a 20 token text using GPT-2 simple. It is taking me around 15 seconds to generate the sentence. AI Dungeon is taking around 4 seconds to generate the same size sentence.

Is there a way to fasten/optimize the GPT-2 text generation?

Answer (score 1):

Text generation models like GPT-2 are slow, and it is of course even worse with bigger models like GPT-J and GPT-NeoX.

If you want to speed up your text generation you have a couple of options:

- Use a GPU. GPT-2 doesn't require too much VRAM so an entry level GPU will do. On a GPU, generating 20 tokens with GPT-2 shouldn't take more than 1 second.
- Quantize your model and convert it to TensorRT. See this good tutorial: https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/tree/main/demo/HuggingFace/GPT2
- Serve it through a dedicated inference server (like TorchServe or Triton Inference Server).

I actually wrote an article about how to speed up inference of transformer based models. You might find it helpful: [how to speed up deep learning inference](https://nlpcloud.io/how-to-speed-up-deep-learning-nlp-transformers-inference.html?utm_source=so&utm_campaign=he5u8885-fd8e-21eb-ca80-5242ac13d5ja)

Answer (score 0):

I think they have quicker results because their program is better optimized and they have greater computing power. They pay a lot for server. As well, Ai Dungeon uses GPT-3 which might be just faster. I'm as well struggling with speed of GPT-2. Let me know if you figured anything.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [OpenVINO](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_overview.html) optimized version of [GPT-2 model](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/tree/master/models/public/gpt-2). The demo can be found [here](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/blob/master/demos/gpt2_text_prediction_demo/python/README.md). It should be much faster as it's heavily optimized.